# I can't open pycharm, how can i do

Tags: pycharm

[image: 1]
When I tried to open pycharm, I encountered this error，How to fix this it?

I can't delete plugin .

Comment: Have you tried to re-install ?

Answer (score -1):

looks like something is wrong with your plugin `jiyuanIME`. Try remove that plugin and restart.

Comment: but in my mac ,i can' find **jiyuanIME**